# Segfault when accessing next node in singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to just reverse a singly linked list, but with a bit of a twist. Rather than having the pointer to the next node be the actual next node, it points to the pointer in that next node.

```
struct _Node
{
    union
    {
        int n;
        char c;
    } val;
    void *ptr; /* points to ptr variable in next node, not beginning */
    int var;
};
typedef struct _Node Node;
```

I know how to reverse a normal singly linked list and I think I have the general idea of how to go about solving this one, but I'm getting a segfault when I'm trying to access `head->ptr`and I don't know why.

```
Node *reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node * temp;
    Node * prev = NULL;
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        temp = head->ptr + 4; /* add 4 to pass union and get beginning of next node */
        head->ptr = prev;
        prev = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Even if I try and access `head->ptr` without adding 4, I get a segfault.

The driver that I have for this code is only an object file, so I can't see how things are being called or anything of the sort. I'm either missing something blatantly obvious or there is an issue in the driver.

Comment: ok, to clarify: head->prev points to "some_other_node.ptr"?

Comment: If you're clarifying what ptr points to, then that's correct.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for making the `ptr` element point to the `ptr` element of the next item in the list, rather than doing things the usual, sane, simple, relatively foolproof way that any normal program would do it, and have `ptr` (probably renamed as `next` and probably not of type `void *` since the type adds another level of complexity or non-portability) pointing to the start of the next element in the list?  It seems perverse.  The only excuse I can think of is "Sadistic Teacher Dictated This".  Otherwise, it is very unlikely to be a sensible decision.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It very much falls under the category of "Sadistic Teached Dictated This"

Comment: he said he has some "driver" code only available as an object file, so obviously, his teacher has a reason, yes ;)

Comment: Stuff happens; stuff has happened to you.   Bad luck.  If it were my task, I'd make sure I had working code with a regular 'pointer to next node'  to do the reversal.  (There are numerous questions for reversing a singly-linked list on SO, with answers.). Then I'd revise the code to deal with the bizarre "pointer to next node's next pointer".  Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit code?  Your offset has problems if you're on an average 64-bit machine (structure padding). Strictly, you need to arithmetic on `char *` and not `void *`; GCC allows you to treat them the same; the standard doesn't.

Comment: The other answer showed me how I should tackle the issues of offset. Still not quite used to problems of this nature, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll show you a major problem in your code:

```
    while (head) // is shorter than while(head != NULL)
    {
        // Where does the 4 come from?
        // And even if: You have to substract it.
        // so, definitively a bug:
        // temp = head->ptr + 4; /* add 4 to pass union and get beginning of next node */
        size_t offset_ptr = (char*)head->ptr - (char*)head;
        // the line above should be moved out of the while loop.
        temp = head->ptr - offset_ptr;
```

Anyways, your algorithm probably won't work as written. If you want to reverse stuff, you are gonna have to work backwards (which is non-trivial in single linked lists). There are two options:

1. count the elements, allocate an array, remember the pointers in that array and then reassign the next pointers.
2. create a temporary double linked list (actually you only need another single reversely linked list, because both lists together form a double linked list). Then walk again to copy the next pointer from your temporary list to the old list. Remember to free the temporary list prior to returning.

Comment: My logic behind the 4 was that the size of the union is 4 bytes to account for the size of the int variable. Subtracting it would tackle the offset problem.

Comment: yea, but what if you get a second object file (with a second header file) that doesn't have a union but instead a struct in it's place? Then you can rewrite your entire code. My solution would still work. That's why we usually do it this way. Never write constants (like "4"), if constant expressions (like "(char*)head->ptr - (char*)head") will do the job.

Comment: Definitely the correct way of looking at it, you're right. I'm left with an infinite loop now, but I guess that's better than a segfault!

Comment: Note that the C standard says that arithmetic on `void *` is undefined (in part because `sizeof(void)` is undefined and not 1).  You should be converting `head->ptr` to `char *` in the `temp = …` line shown.  GCC won't complain unless you force it too (`-pedantic`).

Comment: I understand the need to cast it to something other than `void *` but why are we using `char *` and not, say, `unsigned int *`?

Comment: sizeof(char) is defined to be 1, sizeof(unsigned int) may be anything else. and sizeof("your union") doesn't need to be dividable by sizeof(unsigned int). So, you might not even be able to reach ptr that way. So, we use char*, because that's the only guaranteed way it works (ok, unsigned char and signed char would work, too, but there, we have to type in more)

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and did some tweaking, well in my opinion your code had some logical error. Your pointers were overwritten again and again (jumping from one node to another and back: 1->2 , 2->1) which were leading to suspected memory leaks. Here, a working version of your code...

```
Node *reverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *temp = 0;
    //Re-ordering of your assignment statements
    while (head) //No need for explicit head != NULL 
    {
        //Here this line ensures that pointers are not overwritten
        Node *next = (Node *)head->ptr; //Type casting from void * to Node *
        head->ptr = temp;
        temp = head;
        head = next;
    }
    return temp;
}
```